# menu with Focus add text

Tags: css, responsive-design, focus

I wanna make a menu very small, so  i have the initial letter for each name and i add "focus" but what i want its to appear the full word.
ex:

```
    css:

    .menu:focus {

     }

    php:

    <nav>
    <li class="menu"><a href="home.php>h</a></li><br>
    <li class="menu"><a href="galery.php>g</a></li>
    </nav>
```

> and so you simply see the menu like:
>
> > h
> >
> > g
>
> and if you click in h for ex. you would see:
>
> > home
> >
> > g

how can i do it?

and then if click again go to the link page.

is it possible?

## edit

```
    php:

    <nav>
    <li>
        <span class="m">
            H
        </span>
        <span class="f">
            <a class="menu" href="home.php">
            Home
            </a>
        </span>
    </li>
    </span>

    css:

    nav li .f {
        display: none;
    }

    nav li:hover .f {
        display: inline;
        background-color: #202020;
    }
```

until here ok, you pass by and it shows the full word with the link, but the objective its not just pass by, its to click on it i just change hover to focus and it stops working.

also the hover ".m" display none its not working. it should switch isnt it possible ?

```
    css:

    nav li:focus .f {
        display: inline;
        background-color: #202020;
    }

    nav li: hover .m {
        display: none;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: it is very especific question i was already searching it but i believe some one here can easily give me some light

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have created fiddle for u do you want something like this .

```
<nav>
<li class="menu">
    <a href="home.php">
        <span class="test">h</span><span class="test2">ome</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="menu">
    <a href="home.php">
        <span class="test">g</span><span class="test2">alery</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

```
nav li a .test2{display:none} 
nav li a:focus .test2, nav li a:hover .test2{display:inline}
```

OR if you want javascript solution here is code for u

html

```
<nav class="nav">
<li class="menu">
    <a href="javascript:;" data-url="home.php">
        <span class="test">h</span><span class="test2">ome</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="menu">
    <a href="javascript:;" data-url="gallary.php">
        <span class="test">g</span><span class="test2">alery</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

CSS

```
nav li.menu a .test2{display:none;}
nav li.menu a .test2.open{display:inline;}
```

Jquery

```
$(".nav>li>a").click(function(e) {
    var trig = false;
    var links = $(this).data("url");
    $(this).children(".test2").addClass("open");
    if(trig == false){
        $(this).click(function(e) {
            window.location.href = links;
        });

    }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ismailfarooq/p667L2y0/

Comment: ok thats awesome.. thanks, so in php i cant do what you made in java script?

Comment: i am not sure about that but i think u are definitely cant check click event in php

Comment: it was already a boost on the process maybe i have to learn about javascript also . thanks a lot

Comment: accept this question as a helpful it will be appreciated for me  (y)